# How to use Bayesian Change point library in python which is already there in R studio as bcp?

Tags: r, python-2.7, bigdata, bayesian

I need your help regarding this matter is there any similar library similar to bcp library in R in python. Or is there any method to import R library packages in to the python.

Comment: Please note the descriptions when you are choosing tags.  The `bcp` tag is for the Microsoft/Sybase bulk-copy database utility, not bayesian change point.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [rpy2](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/) module that allows R to be embedded in Python, you can import R packages including `base` into Python:

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro

rpackage = importr("RPackage")    
...
```

**RPY2**

As example, below imports R's XML package and parses the Python string of Google Doodles into a binary object. Then, Python passes the resulting object into R as a native R dataframe, finally launching the View window of data.

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro

xmlpackage = importr("XML") 

doodlexml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <dataroot>
                    <GoogleDoodles>
                        <ID>1</ID>
                        <DoodleDate>2012-02-29</DoodleDate>
                        <Doodle>Gioachino Rossini&apos;s 220th Birthday</Doodle>
                    </GoogleDoodles>
                    <GoogleDoodles>
                        <ID>2</ID>
                        <DoodleDate>2011-02-04</DoodleDate>
                        <Doodle>Family Day 2010</Doodle>
                    </GoogleDoodles>
                    <GoogleDoodles>
                        <ID>3</ID>
                        <DoodleDate>2010-09-01</DoodleDate>
                        <Doodle>First Day of School 2010</Doodle>
                    </GoogleDoodles>
                    <GoogleDoodles>
                        <ID>4</ID>
                        <DoodleDate>2010-09-06</DoodleDate>
                        <Doodle>Google Instant Launch</Doodle>
                    </GoogleDoodles>
                    <GoogleDoodles>
                        <ID>5</ID>
                        <DoodleDate>2010-09-02</DoodleDate>
                        <Doodle>Vietnam National Day 2010</Doodle>
                    </GoogleDoodles>    
                </dataroot>'''

xmldoc = xmlpackage.xmlParse(doodlexml)
pydf = xmlpackage.xmlToDataFrame(nodes = xmlpackage.getNodeSet(xmldoc, "//GoogleDoodles"))

ro.globalenv['rdf'] = pydf
ro.r('View(rdf)')
```

**RScript**

Alternatively, you can simply run R via command line in Python using subprocess even [passing arguments](http://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/) as needed. R comes installed with its automated executable [RScript.exe](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html). This way you can keep everything natively as is inside R:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["RScript", "C:\Path\To\RScript.R"]
a = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,error = a.communicate()  

if a.returncode == 0:                     # R SCRIPT SUCCESSFUL
    print(output.decode("utf-8"))
else:                                     # R SCRIPT FAILURE
    print(error.decode("utf-8"))
```